# Window.DataContext error on path cannot be null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and trying to figure out how it works by following along with a tutorial and then adapting the code to a simple project. However I am having an issue where the `MainWindow` will **not** load other views even though it is switching the CurrentViewModel.

Visual Studio is highlighting the following error in the XAML of the **MainWindow.xaml** code:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path

For the purposes of this question I am specifically asking about the *cause of this error* and *what affect* it is having on the *project*.

Here is the code for the project at the moment:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Address_Manager.Model
{
    public class StoreAddressModel { }

    public class StoreAddress : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _storeCode;
        private string _storeName;
        private string _address1;
        private string _address2;
        private string _city;
        private string _state;
        private string _postCode;
        private string _phone;
        private string _email;
        private string _country;
        private string _manager;
        private string _areaManager;
        private List<string> _openingHours;
        public string StoreCode
        {
            get { return _storeCode; }
            set
            {
                if (_storeCode != value) { _storeCode = value; RaisePropertyChanged("StoreCode"); }
            }
        }
        public string StoreName
        {
            get { return _storeName; }
            set
            {
                if (_storeName != value) { _storeName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("StoreName"); }
            }
        }
        public string Address1
        {
            get { return _address1; }
            set
            {
                if (_address1 != value) { _address1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Address1"); }
            }
        }
        public string Address2
        {
            get { return _address2; }
            set
            {
                if (_address2 != value) { _address2 = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Address2"); }
            }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set
            {
                if (_city != value) { _city = value; RaisePropertyChanged("City"); }
            }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                if (_state != value) { _state = value; RaisePropertyChanged("State"); }
            }
        }
        public string PostCode
        {
            get { return _postCode; }
            set
            {
                if (_postCode != value) { _postCode = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PostCode"); }
            }
        }
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return _phone; }
            set
            {
                if (_phone != value) { _phone = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Phone"); }
            }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set
            {
                if (_email != value) { _email = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Email"); }
            }
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get { return _country; }
            set
            {
                if (_country != value) { _country = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Country"); }
            }
        }
        public string Manager
        {
            get { return _manager; }
            set
            {
                if (_manager != value) { _manager = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Manager"); }
            }
        }
        public string AreaManager
        {
            get { return _areaManager; }
            set
            {
                if (_areaManager != value) { _areaManager = value; RaisePropertyChanged("AreaManager"); }
            }
        }
        public List<string> OpeningHours
        {
            get { return _openingHours; }
            set
            {
                if (_openingHours != value) { _openingHours = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OpeningHours"); }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Address_Manager.ViewModel;

namespace Address_Manager
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            NavCommand = new MyICommand<string>(OnNav);
        }

        private StoreAddressViewModel storeAddressViewModel = new StoreAddressViewModel();
        private OfficeAddressViewModel officeAddressViewModel = new OfficeAddressViewModel();
        private BindableBase _CurrentViewModel;
        public BindableBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return _CurrentViewModel; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _CurrentViewModel, value); }
        }

        public MyICommand<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }

        private void OnNav(string destination)
        {
            switch (destination)
            {
                case "office":
                    CurrentViewModel = officeAddressViewModel;
                    break;
                case "stores":
                    CurrentViewModel = storeAddressViewModel;
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    break;
                default:
                    CurrentViewModel = storeAddressViewModel;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Address_Manager.ViewModel
{
    class OfficeAddressViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    }
}
```

```
using Address_Manager.Model;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Address_Manager.ViewModel
{
    class StoreAddressViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public StoreAddressViewModel()
        {
            LoadStores();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<StoreAddress> StoreDetails { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Stores { get; set; }

        public void LoadStores()
        {
            ObservableCollection<StoreAddress> _StoreDetails = new ObservableCollection<StoreAddress>();
            ObservableCollection<string> _Stores = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            string addressRepository = "";
            addressRepository = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReferenceFilePath"];
            List<string> rawStoreData = new List<string>();
            rawStoreData = File.ReadAllLines(addressRepository).ToList();
            foreach (string line in rawStoreData)
            {
                string[] segments = line.Split(',');
                StoreAddress store = new StoreAddress
                {
                    StoreCode = segments[0],
                    StoreName = segments[1],
                    Address1 = segments[2],
                    Address2 = segments[3],
                    City = segments[4],
                    State = segments[5],
                    PostCode = segments[6],
                    Country = segments[7],
                    Phone = segments[8],
                    Email = segments[9],
                    Manager = segments[10],
                    AreaManager = segments[11],
                    OpeningHours = segments[12].Split('|').ToList()
                };
                _StoreDetails.Add(store);

                _Stores.Add(store.StoreName);
            }
            if (_Stores != null)
                StoreDetails = _StoreDetails;
        }

    }
}
```

Views:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Address_Manager.Views.OffcieAddressView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Address_Manager.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="440" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="PlaceHolder"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Address_Manager.Views.StoreAddressView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Address_Manager.Views"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:Address_Manager.Model"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="440" d:DesignWidth="850">


    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
<Window x:Class="Address_Manager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Address_Manager"
        xmlns:views ="clr-namespace:Address_Manager.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels ="clr-namespace:Address_Manager.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:StoreAddressViewModel}">
            <views:StoreAddressView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:OfficeAddressViewModel}">
            <views:OffcieAddressView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="NavBar">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Stores"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="stores"
                Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="Office"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="office"
                Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Button Content="Exit"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="exit"
                Grid.Column="5"/>

        </Grid>


        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

ICommand and BindableBase classes:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace Address_Manager
{
    public class MyICommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        Action<T> _TargetExecuteMethod;
        Func<T, bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

        public MyICommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        }

        public MyICommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
            _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {

            if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
            {
                T tparm = (T)parameter;
                return _TargetCanExecuteMethod(tparm);
            }

            if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime is longer than lifetime of UI objects that get hooked up to command

        // Prism commands solve this in their implementation 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod?.Invoke((T)parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Address_Manager
{
    class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(member, val))
                return false;

            member = val;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. An error occurs when opening a file. You pass the parameter 'null' to the method.
2. You do not have a file existence check.

Rewrite your StoreAddressViewModel:

```
using Address_Manager.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Address_Manager.ViewModel
{
    class StoreAddressViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public StoreAddressViewModel()
        {
            LoadStores();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<StoreAddress> _StoreDetails = new ObservableCollection<StoreAddress>();
        public ObservableCollection<StoreAddress> StoreDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return _StoreDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                _StoreDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> _Stores = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Stores
        {
            get
            {
                return _Stores;
            }
            set
            {
                _Stores = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void LoadStores()
        {
            StoreDetails.Clear();
            Stores.Clear();

            string addressRepository = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReferenceFilePath"];

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressRepository) && File.Exists(addressRepository))
            {
                List<string> rawStoreData = new List<string>();
                rawStoreData = File.ReadAllLines(addressRepository).ToList();
                foreach (string line in rawStoreData)
                {
                    string[] segments = line.Split(',');
                    StoreAddress store = new StoreAddress
                    {
                        StoreCode = segments[0],
                        StoreName = segments[1],
                        Address1 = segments[2],
                        Address2 = segments[3],
                        City = segments[4],
                        State = segments[5],
                        PostCode = segments[6],
                        Country = segments[7],
                        Phone = segments[8],
                        Email = segments[9],
                        Manager = segments[10],
                        AreaManager = segments[11],
                        OpeningHours = segments[12].Split('|').ToList()
                    };
                    StoreDetails.Add(store);
                    Stores.Add(store.StoreName);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

P.S.: this code has always returned true since the _Stores sheet is already defined in the method with 0 size

```
if (_Stores != null)
 StoreDetails = _StoreDetails;
```

Comment: Would have been better if screenshot was in _English_

Comment: @MickyD sorry, but even if I change the environment language VS - the tex error does not change and is written in the language of the operating system

Comment: @MickyD While that's true I think that the explanation is clear enough, and the sample code provided is sufficient to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ГеннадийКурбесов Thank you for the quick response. At first I thought this did not work, but after I recompiled the project the error has disappeared.

Comment: @ГеннадийКурбесов Your sample code should read !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressRepository) though, otherwise the following code block will not execute.

Comment: @HiKaizer I said _"Would have been better"_.  I actually up-voted